# Non-associativeness of composition in deductive systems?

Tags: logic, category-theory, intuition, math-history, philosophy

WARNING: The first three and last two paragraphs of this question concern historical/philosophical matters related to a secondary aim of the question. If you are more interested in the properly mathematical part of it, you are invited to skip them as you wish.

BEGINNING OF THE HISTORICAL/PHILOSOPHICAL PART OF THE QUESTION

I begin with a small and (probably excessively, but also harmlessly) simplified introduction. The notion of *category* seems to have been historically inspired by a common pattern emerging everywhere in the mathematical 'zoo' after the notion of *function* between *sets* had been sufficiently established. Since the composition of functions turns out to be associative in virtually all historical examples (and **how** could it not be?!), the composition of *morphisms* in a category is axiomatized to be associative as well.

After being properly abstracted from such examples, category theory found its way of application in a much broader class of situations. In particular, there are the notions of *enrichment* and *internalization*, which permit some 'animals' that have been historically thought as *objects* in a category, to be treated as categories themselves, allowing quite fruitful generalizations and better understanding. This clearly surpasses the original aim of category theory (even under a less simplified perspective on its historical development, I believe).

At this point, however, the associativeness axiom seems to start charging its price: it's much more difficult, if not impossible, to apply the notions of enrichment and internalization when dealing with objects that involve some kind of non-associativeness. Thus, it sounds quite natural to ask: is it possible to relax the definition of a category with respect to the associativeness of composition and still get some reasonable theory to deal with? Curiously, such a notion of 'non-associative category' happens to appear in another application that category theory has found in its history: Logic.

END OF THE HISTORICAL/PHILOSOPHICAL PART OF THE QUESTION

Indeed, a *deductive system* (as defined, for example, in the book 'Introduction to higher order categorical logic' by Lambek and Scott) is precisely a category without the associativeness axiom. As the authors put it,

> 'Logicians will think of the objects of a deductive system as *formulas*, of the arrows as *proofs* (or *deductions*) and of an operation on arrows as a *rule of inference*.' (p.47)

And they stress:

> 'Logicians should note that a deductive system is concerned not just with unlabelled entailments or sequents $A\rightarrow B$ (as in Gentzen's proof theory), but with deductions or proofs of such entailments.' (p.47)

In other words, as I understand it, deductive systems should be thought as being accompanied by some concrete 'models' of the systems themselves. Unfortunately, I was not able to find examples of such deductive systems and their concrete 'models' that put in relief the non-associativeness of the composition in this framework. Indeed, the authors add that

> '(...) from any deductive system one may obtain a category by imposing a suitable equivalence relation between proofs.' (p.52)

The first aim of this question is to ask:

> What are some good examples of the role played by non-associativeness in the framework of deductive systems?

Let me elaborate on an attempt I made to imagine what such examples might look like. (I'll now possibly enter a totally amateurish way of expression; hopefully logicians won't despise me because of that! =] )

Imagine you have a formula that can be proved easily by using some induction step, or less easily without using it. Then these proofs are clearly not equivalent, but this non-equivalence doesn't have anything to do with non-associativeness of the composition of inferences: rather, the distinction between them lies much earlier than that, on the assumptions you make before starting your reasoning.

Now, imagine you have a formula that can be proved easily by using two induction steps, and less easily by using only one induction step, but starting with the same assumptions in both cases. Would this example be suitable for reflecting the non-associativeness of composition in a deductive system? What a relation making these two proofs equivalent would look like? Are there examples of concrete 'models' of deductive systems for which there are proofs that can't be made equivalent by any reasonable relation, thus making non-associativeness unavoidable? Evidently, 'reasonable' here is to be understood in relation to the concrete 'model'.

EPILOGUE OF THE HISTORICAL/PHILOSOPHICAL PART OF THE QUESTION

Finally, the secondary aim of this question: why is it so difficult to find some natural phenomena for which the appropriate notion of composition is non-associative? Is it just our still prevalent addiction to the language of sets, or there's something more subtle about that? How would you put in words your intuition about the associativeness of composition in general?

Comments about any aspects of the question as a whole will also be appreciated.

Comment: This question would *really* benefit from the historical background being removed, in my opinion; it's unnecessarily long right now, and could be much briefer and easier to read.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for the suggestion! Instead of removing it, since I am also interested in any comments about the historical/philosophical part of the question, I am inclined to add a warning at the beginning, so that those who are not interested in the historical/philosophical part can skip it if they wish. Does it seem reasonable to you?

Comment: I don't know what Lambek and Scott have in mind for a concrete definition of proof, but I feel that in any reasonable definition, composition must be concatenation, and concatenation is certainly associative. But perhaps the authors are thinking of a very primitive notion of proof where composition has to be defined by concatenation _plus_ renaming variables or something unpleasant like that.

Comment: Associativity is a key feature of categories, nevertheless it also often appears in more relaxed forms, e.g. in monoidal categories or bicategories. Examples of almost associative operations are Cartesian product of sets: we don't have a strict equality $(A\times B)\times C=A\times(B\times C)$, only a natural isomorphism between them; or the composition of paths of a topological space. Probably a similar situation arises with the formal proofs of your research.

Comment: @ZhenLin I like your use of the word 'concatenation' because it summons in my imaginary one of the first situations in which associativeness has been seriously questioned, and at the same time one that, in my opinion, strongly contributed to the emergence of the notion of category, since it could arguably be considered one of the first distinguished functors to have appeared (I purposedly omitted it from the historical/philosophical discussion above for the sake of simplicity): the discovery of the fundamental group of a topological space.

Comment: Indeed, it's definition strongly relies on the concatenation of paths, and the group structure is only possible due to associativeness 'modulo homotopy'. But still, in that case all the problem relative to associativeness seem to come from the need of formalizing the notion of path by means of continuous functions defined on an interval, which doesn't mean this example couldn't be inspiring for many interesting abstractions.

Comment: Actually, I don't agree there. You can construct a _monoid_ whose elements are loops of variable length and whose operation is given by concatenation (without rescaling!). This is strictly unital and associative, _without_ passing to homotopy classes. You pass to homotopy classes to get _inverses_.

Comment: @Berci If one thinks in terms of universal properties, then even the Cartesian product $A\times B$ itself is only well-defined modulo some isomorphism, isn't that right? I'm not sure though if the word 'natural' would be applicable here as in the example you gave relatively to associativeness.

Comment: @ZhenLin Are you sure? I'm trying to imagine how it could be done, but I can't. Maybe that's just because I still carry the strong impression the old picture of a square with two parallel diagonal lines on it made on me when I first met it. I admit a different construction might exist, though. Can you give some hint on how to do that? =]

Comment: As I said, you need to allow loops of variable length. The concatenation of a loop of length $a$ with a loop of length $b$ results in a loop of length $a + b$. If you only consider loops of fixed length, say $1$, then you need to rescale after concatenation and this is where associativity fails.

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh, now I see! You just define a path to be a *pair* of interval and continuous function, then think of concatenation as an operation on *both*, and associativeness comes for free! Nice, I never heard about that before. Thanks!

Comment: Well, (using a given set theory), particularly in the category of sets, Cartesian product typically has a very specific construction, as set of ordered pairs, and that is not strictly associative. In general, you are right, direct product is defined only up to isomorphism, nevertheless one often wants to use it as a functor, whence a choice for each pair of objects is needed to make in the background.